# Drop duplicates, but ignore nulls

Tags: python, pandas

So I know you can use something like this to drop duplicate lines:

```
the_data.drop_duplicates(subset=['the_key'])
```

However, if `the_key` is null for some values, like below:

```
   the_key  C  D
1      NaN  *  *
2      NaN     *
3      111  *  *
4      111
```

It will keep the ones marked in the `C` column. Is it possible to get `drop_duplicates` to treat all `nan` as distinct and get an output keeping the data like in the `D` column?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(~df['the_key'].duplicated()) | df['the_key'].isna()]
#fol oldier pandas versions
#df = df[(~df['the_key'].duplicated()) | df['the_key'].isnull()]
print (df)
   the_key  C    D
1      NaN  *    *
2      NaN       * 
3    111.0  *    *
```

Comment: Especially good because I've got that the wee `oldier pandas`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way:

```
dupes = the_data.duplicated(subset=['the_key'])
dupes[the_data['the_key'].isnull()] = False
the_data = the_data[~dupes]
```